# Electrons direction in cathode ray tube

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrons

This image below show the **movement of an electron** in a **magnetic field**, it's taken from the video [[Histoire des sciences] La découverte de l'électron](https://youtu.be/WHoH5m83Ga0) explaining the experience of J.J. Thompson when he discovered the electron.

[image: Cathode ray tube]

I don't understand why electrons are going the way indicated the red dotted line. Below is how I understand this image with the **right-hand rule**:

[image: Cathode ray tube (edited)]

Because the force $\vec{F}$ is oriented toward the top, a positively charged ion (or cation) should go toward the top as shown on the picture. But here, it's an electron, a negatively charged particle, so it should be going toward the bottom. So why is it going toward the top? What's wrong in my understanding?

Also, is it correct to mark a **plus** (+) and a **minus** (-) on the **magnet**?

Answer (score 1):

The force on a particle with charge $q$ and velocity $\vec{v}$ due to a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is given by $\vec{F} = q(\vec{v} \times \vec{B})$. For an electron, $q$ is of course negative. For the geometry in the figures you posted, $\vec{v} \times \vec{B}$ points downward, and hence the force is upward.

In terms of the vectors in the second figure, I suppose $\vec{I}$ indicates the direction of current flow, which is in the opposite direction of electron flow. The right hand rule says that the force is in the direction of $\vec{I}\times\vec{B}$, which again is upward, as you can deduce by aligning your thumb with $\vec{B}$ and your middle finger with $\vec{I}$, whereby your index finger will point upward. For a positively charged particle, $\vec{I}$, and hence $\vec{F}$, would have the opposite orientation.

Marking a whole magnet plus or minus doesn't make much sense. Magnets have two poles: north and south. Outside the magnet, $\vec{B}$ tends to point from north to south. In this case, the magnet you labeled with a plus likely has its north pole facing the tube, while the other magnet has its south pole facing the tube. The two cylinders in the figure could also be (and I suppose usually are in practice) two different poles of the same magnet.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see what's wrong in my understanding...

Comment: With $\vec{I}$ oriented as shown in your second figure, you will find by applying the right hand rule that $\vec{F}$ is upward. But this direction of $\vec{I}$ assumes that the particles are negatively charged: otherwise $\vec{I}$ would point in the opposite direction and $\vec{F}$ would be downward.